# Rename multiple folders using shell script without matching a pattern

Tags: shell

How to rename multiple folder/files by user defined.

Say for Ex. I have multiple folders like krish, moorthy, ravi, robert, etc..

I want to rename all these directories as script_1 , script_2, script_3 etc

I tried below script but it doesnt produce a output

for i in * do mv $* $script_'$i' done

while executing it says it cannot move, cannot stat *

Please help me to go through this.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong with your script, that it is difficult to know where to begin.

First, the syntax needs end-of-line markers:

```
for i in *; do mv $* $script_'$i'; done
```

Now the `mv` parameter 1 needs to be the name of the current file:

```
for i in *; do mv $i $script_'$i'; done
```

Next the `mv` parameter 2 has three errors (`$script_` expands the non-existent variable `script_`; the quotes in `'$i'` make it a literal; and you need a second variable with a count in it to expand to the name you want), so you need something like:

```
n=1; for i in *; do mv $i script_$n; ((++n)); done
```

This will work, provided there are no blanks in the file names and provided there are no non-directory files in the current directory. So lastly we arrive at:

```
n=1; for i in *; do if [ -d "$i" ]; then mv "$i" script_$n; ((++n)); fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl-rename` is well suited for this:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir foo bar baz
$ perl-rename --dry-run --verbose 's/.*/sprintf "script_%04d", ++$main::Mad/e' ./*/
./bar/ -> script_0001
./baz/ -> script_0002
./foo/ -> script_0003
```